# Fields based on record type on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, describesobject, describefieldresult

Suppose I have two record types on a standard object, suppose Opportunity, and out of 100 fields in object, lets say for each record type 50-50 fields are made available to user to enter data on the page layout assigned to the record type.

A small question here again : apex:detail can be used in create mode?? so that, I can override save and cancel functionality.

Thanks
Phani

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true. You'll normally have a different detail page for each record type as you're creating a new record. You'll be able to save or cancel creation of the new record. Clone would be another option as well if starting from a detail page.

What you can also do to really help your users out is create publisher actions, one for each record type. Any fields that can be populated for that record type can be pre-filled using the publisher action and those which don't apply to the record type won't be visible to your users.